# Define second ng-click in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Here is code to click button text color using AngularJS.

```
<button ng-class="myClass"
   ng-click="myClass='red'"
   ng-init="myClass='blue'">
some text
</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rLkb5/2/

Is it possible to change the color to green on the second click? (blue->red->green)

My gut tells me it's impossible without controller+custom JS code but there may be a simple way.

Comment: Why do you feel the need to do a state change operation without a controller? Doesn't this state need to be stored somewhere anyway? The solutions provided below will work, but they require you to put a fair bit of logic into your template, which is inelegant, will hinder testing, and will make the code less portable. Can you elaborate on your use case a little more?

Comment: @JoshDavidMiller There is no use case.  I just asked if it is possible to do foo in bar way.  It sounded strange for me that some method works with 2 states but not with 3 states, though I understand the first red->blue is not about states.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if this is acceptable

```
<div ng-app>
    <button ng-class="myClass" ng-click="counter = counter + 1; myClass=classes[counter % 3]" ng-init="myClass='blue'; classes=['blue', 'red', 'green']; counter=0">some text</button>
</div>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rLkb5/3/)

Comment: Hmm, a bit more robust than my example :D

Answer (score 1):

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.active = false;
  $scope.toggleActive = function () {
    $scope.active = !$scope.active; 
 };
}
```

.

```
<div ng-class="{red: !active, green: active}" ng-click="toggleActive()"></div>
```

`ngClass`, when given an object, sets the classes of which property values are truthful.

Note: View's should not contain any business logic as they are hard to test; they only should interact with the controller.

Clarifition on that:

What you shouldn't do is, to change properties in scope directly from your view. Have a function in controller acts as a wrapper which does that for you. View can change how itself is rendered depending on the scope properties and call functions in controller to manipulate data. Also, controllers should not aware of *at all* how you want to *display* the data, it should behave like there is no view at all (That in fact, view should be replacable). Which css class you want to apply is not something your controller should know / decide.

Comment: Right, View's should not contain business logic.  Then shouldn't I even use the first example to change color from red to blue using View?

Comment: Got it!  Too bad I don't have right to vote up yet.  I hope somebody else does.

Answer (score 0):

There is probable a better way, but if you rename your classes:

```
.statetrue{
  color:red
}

.statefalse{
  color:blue
}
```

Then, your button:

```
<button ng-class="'state' + myClass" ng-click="myClass = !myClass"  ng-init="myClass=true">
```

Comment: Where is green by the way? :)